# enable_if's syntactical patterns

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, enable-if

I've been using `enable_if` in this approximate manner with various versions of GCC (up to 5.2):

```
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< b >... >
void fn() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< !b >... >
void fn() { std::cout << 2 << std::endl; }
// ...
fn< true >();
fn< false >();
```

But, as it turns out, Clang 3.7 does not accept this ("call to 'fn' is ambiguous").

**Q1. Who's right, and why?**

There are, of course, other ways to do it, but I kind of don't like

```
template< bool b >
std::enable_if_t< b, void > fa() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
// ...
```

and its ilk for making normal parts of the function signature less readable, and

```
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< b, int > = 0 >
void fd() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
// ...
```

for involving irrelevant elements (types and values).

**Q2. What other (correct, more readable, less hackish/weird) ways to use `enable_if`/`enable_if_t` are there?**

Comment: Yeah I don't like them either but there's probably a reason everyone's doing it that way. Blame C++.

Comment: How about `template <bool b, class = std::enable_if_t<b>>` ?

Comment: The more readable way is concepts/constraints, once they become part of the language.

Comment: @Quentin That's an error in both compilers.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t< b >...` makes no sense. You are declaring a template parameter pack of type `void`.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10377183/

Comment: @vpozdyayev Indeed. Tonight is not SFINAE night for me !

Comment: @T.C. So, that's a GCC bug? That said, using `std::enable_if_t< b, int >...` makes no difference.

Comment: @dyp Looks like it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the standard *14.1/p7 Template parameters [temp.param]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **A non-type template-parameter shall not be declared to have** floating point, class, or **void type**.

Consequently, your code snippet is ill-formed. Thus, GCC is wrong on this.

However if you change to:

```
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< b, int>... >
void fn() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< !b, int>... >
void fn() { std::cout << 2 << std::endl; }
```

Restriction is lifted, and this code is legitimate and should be accepted. Apparently, it seems that Clang rejects this code as well. IMHO, this is a Clang bug.

As I found out a similar bug has been reported [23840](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23840).

Now for the practical part, I don't know if this is practical/less hackish/less weird but you could do the following:

```
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< b, int> = 0 >
void fn() { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
template< bool b, std::enable_if_t< !b, int> = 0 >
void fn() { std::cout << 2 << std::endl; }
```

Comment: So we fix this by adding some valid type for `enable_if`, but clang still complains: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/870a4fe0ba9406ce IMHO, your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @dyp The code you posted should be accepted, I think this is a Clang bug https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23840

Comment: Looks similar to the https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11723 I've indirectly linked to in my comment to the OP.

Comment: Not so sure about 14.1/7, since we are dealing with unexpanded parameter packs, not parameters as such ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23711944)). It's somewhat like the type "list of <bottom type>" having the empty list as a valid instance even though the bottom type has no instances. On the other hand, we have 14.6/8 "If every valid specialization...". On the other other hand (sic), this item appears to be controversial itself, see, e.g., [this issue](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/msg4470).

Comment: Accepting regardless. Apparently, even people at std-discussion find those std paragraphs rather tricky :/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'd use `enable_if` at all here. You're not trying to constrain an overload set, so I'd call that counter-idomatic.

Simple specialization seems to work just fine:

```
template <bool> void fn();
template <> void fn<true>() { std::cout << "true fn\n"; }
template <> void fn<false>() { std::cout << "false fn\n"; }
```

Comment: I'm not trying to solve any particular problem here, except the "how to use `enable_if`" one. This is the answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

> Q2. What other (correct, more readable, less hackish/weird) ways to use enable_if/enable_if_t are there?

arguably, this is more readable and less hackish?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template< bool b >
auto fn() -> std::enable_if_t<b>
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

template< bool b>
auto fn() -> std::enable_if_t<!b>
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}
// ...


auto main() -> int
{
    fn< true >();
    fn< false >();
    return 0;
}
```

and here's another way which could be thought of as more expressive:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool b> using When = std::enable_if_t<b, bool>;
template <bool b> using Unless = std::enable_if_t<!b, bool>;

template< bool b, When<b> = true>
void fn2()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

template< bool b, Unless<b> = true>
void fn2()
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    fn2< true >();
    fn2< false >();
    return 0;
}
```

... or perhaps something like this is more expressive?

```
template <bool b> using Eval = std::integral_constant<bool, b>;

template<bool b>
void fn3()
{
    struct fn3_impl
    {
        static void when(std::true_type)
        {
            std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
        }

        static void when(std::false_type)
        {
            std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
        }
    };

    fn3_impl::when(Eval<b>());
}
```