# Why do my SFINAE expressions no longer work with GCC 8.2?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, language-lawyer, sfinae

I recently upgraded GCC to 8.2, and most of my SFINAE expressions have stopped working.

The following is somewhat simplified, but demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Class {
public:
    template <
        typename U,
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value, int
        >::type...
    >
    void test() {
        std::cout << "Constant" << std::endl;
    }

    template <
        typename U,
        typename std::enable_if<
            !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value, int
        >::type...
    >
    void test() {
        std::cout << "Mutable" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Class c;
    c.test<int &>();
    c.test<int const &>();
    return 0;
}
```

[C++ (gcc) – Try It Online](https://tio.run/##zVLBagMhEL37FTaFkkC69LwrXnLuMefFzE6K4KrouFDCfvtGTUga0mMP9TA6b96bmQeC9@9fAMvyqi2YNCAX2kUKqEbJ7hh9e@wpKE1RMgZGxch3NZ6YTwejoWU8H8LRG0VZUdMKZalVI/L99hmLNLRtfh4M9vp4F5VTazr24Gwk8SgJOLoJ@4BHDGgBxV62baHka1Im4ZZrS7d212LTNBWSNU5OD3nhSOtNdvEwFVwiLgRf7cpsZWlVsuuyg@kqe2Z/bvnlP3j@TFSW@93y3DGWp/BRaXvrcfkJcOFAU/qLQnqT680TWK39KAWkFCz/6NjMluUM)

[C++ (clang) – Try It Online](https://tio.run/##zVJNawMhEL37K2wKJYF06dkVLzn3mPNi3EkR/ELHhRL2t2/UhKQhPfZQD6Pz5r2ZeaAK4V0Z6b6W5VU7ZfIIlGufMIK0gtwx/A4wYJQakyCkSFKiuxZPJOSD0YoRWg6CDUZiUbS0QUXqpAW63z5jCUfGyvNgYNDHu6ieVtNpUN4l5I@SCNZPMEQ4QgSngO8FY5VSrkmaDFuqHd7aXYtd1zVItDh5PZaFE643xcXDVOUzUs7paldnS4erml2XHU3f2DP5c8sv/8HzZ8a63O@W556QMoVaqd2tx@UnqAtHdbU/r6Q3sd48gc3aj1IEzNHRj57MZFnO)

Older versions of GCC (unfortunately I don't remember the exact version I had installed previously) as well as Clang compile the above code just fine, but GCC 8.2 gives an error stating:

> ```
>  : In function 'int main()':
> :29:19: error: call of overloaded 'test()' is ambiguous
>      c.test();
>                    ^
> :12:10: note: candidate: 'void Class::test() [with U = int&; typename std::enable_if::type>::value>::type ... = {}]'
>      void test() {
>           ^~~~
> :22:10: note: candidate: 'void Class::test() [with U = int&; typename std::enable_if::type>::value)>::type ... = {}]'
>      void test() {
>           ^~~~
> :30:25: error: call of overloaded 'test()' is ambiguous
>      c.test();
>                          ^
> :12:10: note: candidate: 'void Class::test() [with U = const int&; typename std::enable_if::type>::value>::type ... = {}]'
>      void test() {
>           ^~~~
> :22:10: note: candidate: 'void Class::test() [with U = const int&; typename std::enable_if::type>::value)>::type ... = {}]'
>      void test() {
> ```

As is usually the case when different compilers and compiler versions handle the same code differently I assume I am invoking undefined behavior. What does the standard have to say about the above code? What am I doing wrong?

---

**Note:** The question is not for ways to fix this, there are several that come to mind. The question is *why* this doesn't work with GCC 8 - is it undefined by the standard, or is it a compiler bug?

**Note 2:** Since everyone was jumping on the default `void` type of `std::enable_if`, I've changed the question to use `int` instead. The problem remains.

**Note 3:** [GCC bug report created](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86932)

Comment: Going by [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/qeS6vm), it worked as late as `gcc 7.3` (and you can see in the assembly that it does the correct thing).

Comment: what are you tying to expand with the `...` after `::type` ?

Comment: What does the ellipsis stands for here? If the condition is true, then there is effectively `template <typename U, void...>`.

Comment: Good point, that's a relic from simplifying the code. Replacing the default `void` with `int` causes the same effect. The original code uses a memberless enum to prevent accidentally specifying a second template paramter.

Comment: How about removing ellipsis?

Comment: Removing ellipsis, replacing the default `void` by `int` and adding a default fixes the problem, yes. The real question is, what is it about the above code that worked fine before, but doesn't work any more with GCC 8?

Comment: More simplified example of the same problem I think: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xFX6AzuqMB7GSa87.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isn't non-type parameter pack that evaluates to "void..." illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401376/isnt-non-type-parameter-pack-that-evaluates-to-void-illegal)

Comment: @DanielLangr That one fails in the exact opposite gcc versions as the one in the question...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sure, but the cause should be the very same.

Comment: @xskxzr By that question, `void...` is legal for and only for empty parameter packs, which is exactly what is desired here. Even if it were illegal, replacing the default `void` with `int` in the `std::enable_if`doesn't change anything about the question.

Comment: Minimal example: https://godbolt.org/g/P9z1pt gcc7.1 OK gcc 8.x KO

Comment: funny, without the second definition: https://godbolt.org/g/RgwSVJ gcc7.1 KO, gcc 8.x OK

Comment: @YSC That's because `f` in your second example only exists for a constant template parameter.

Comment: This is weird: https://godbolt.org/g/mnWcg6 gcc7.1 OK, gcc 8.x OK

Comment: @zennehoy Yes, but `f<int>` is called!

Comment: It reaaaaaly looks like a gcc bug.

Comment: @YSC Not quite, the attempt to call `f<int>` results in an error, since `f` only exists for e.g. `f<const int>`. Also, the non-type `void...` template parameter pack is not the problem - feel free to replace the `std::enable_if` type from `void` to e.g. `int`.

Comment: @zennehoy _that's_ what strange: on gcc 8.1, `f<int>()` succeeds. Look: https://godbolt.org/g/RgwSVJ

Comment: @YSC Ah yes, sorry, I was only looking at the 7.1 column. Something is definitely strange here... (Clang also gives an error as I would expect).

Comment: About that specific point, I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51789825/5470596

Comment: Emm... I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10377183/5376789) is a more proper duplicate, though new versions of the compilers interchange their behaviors, interesting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my take on it. In short, clang is right and gcc has a regression.

We have according to [[temp.deduct]p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#7):

> The substitution occurs in all types and expressions that are used in the function type and in template parameter declarations. [...]

This means that the substitution has to happen whether or not the pack is empty or not. Because we are still in the immediate context, this is SFINAE-able.

Next we have that a variadic parameter is indeed considered an actual template parameter; from [[temp.variadic]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#1)

> A *template parameter pack* is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments.

and [[temp.param]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4) says which non-type template parameters are allowed:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - a type that is literal, has strong structural equality ([class.compare.default]), has no mutable or volatile subobjects, and in which if there is a defaulted member operator<=>, then it is declared public,
> - an lvalue reference type,
> - a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]), or
> - a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).

Note that `void` doesn't fit the bill, your code (as posted) is ill-formed.

Comment: The problem is not the `void` default type of `std::enable_if`! If I understand your answer correctly, SFINAE should work fine for a different type (e.g. `int`). It doesn't under GCC 8.2.

Comment: @zennehoy That's why I said in the second sentence "regression if not `void`" :)

Comment: Do you mind reducing your answer to that? I've specified `int` as the type for `std::enable_if` in the question now, since I really didn't intend to start the discussion of `void...`, which was originally a relic of my simplifying the code. Note that others come to a different conclusion than you btw: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23711944/694509 :)

Comment: @zennehoy I don't really understand the answer; thanks though

Comment: @zenn that other answer is incorrect, since this is not a pack expansion. It's merely a nonexpanding template parameter pack which, had you given it a name, could be expanded elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a language lawyer, but cannot the following quote be somehow connected to the problem?

> [[temp.deduct.type/9]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#9): If Pi is a pack expansion, then the pattern of Pi is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list of A. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by Pi.

It seems to me that since there is no *remaining argument in the template argument list*, then there no comparison of the *pattern* (which contains `enable_if`). If there is no comparison, then there is also no deduction and substitution occurs after deduction I believe. Consequently, if there is no substitution, no SFINAE is applied.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am not sure whether this particular paragraph applies here, but there are more similar rules regarding pack expansion in [temp.deduct]. Also, this discussion can help someone more experienced to resolve the whole issue: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/JwZiV2rrX1A.

Comment: Interestingly, that discussion comes to the conclusion that this was a bug in Clang that was subsequently fixed! There seems to be quite a bit of uncertainty about this in the standard...

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: use `typename = typename enable_if<...>, T=0` with different `T`s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Class {
public:
    template <
        typename U,
        typename = typename std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value
        >, int = 0
    >
    void test() {
        std::cout << "Constant" << std::endl;
    }

    template <
        typename U,
        typename = typename  std::enable_if_t<
            !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<U>::type>::value
        >, char = 0
    >
    void test() {
        std::cout << "Mutable" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Class c;
    c.test<int &>();
    c.test<int const &>();
    return 0;
}
```

([demo](https://tio.run/##rVJNawMhEL37K2wKJYGk5LxrvOTcY86LmZ20grqLjgsl7G/fqinZhhQKbecwzjzffDwR@n7zCjBNj9qBiS1yobtAHpWVbMbovceGvNIUJGNgVAh8X/yZ9fFoNFSMJyO0vVGUKkpaoFTqlEV@WN9juzkM1FZVCo8GG31qaO6Qrdzq0EDnAonbIo@2G7DxeEKPDlAcZFVlSjoGZSJeO8k1147S1G2BZPFDp9u0eKDlKqm5GQhdJC4EX@zzWOVokbPPTVtTF/bI/ir9B@0P/yYe3pT/hfqXSHm178WPNWP5Ua3S7trj8jfgwoHn3F9k0pNcru7AIuvLlUeK3vFtzcZp@gA))

Still trying to figure out what the heck does `std::enable_if<...>::type...` mean knowing the [default type is `void`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23711944/694509, basically it requires the parameter pack to be empty. Feel free to add `int` to replace the default `void` type - that doesn't change anything about the question.

Comment: @zennehoy Note: without the added tparam (`int` & `char`), your two templates functions have the same template signature, hence the ambiguity. What I don't get is why it ever worked before.

Comment: How so? One of them is `template <typename U, void...>` and the other is SFINAE, i.e. `template <typename U, [error: std::enable_if has no member type]...>`.

Comment: @YSC: `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>` requires "strange" extra dummy parameter, better to use `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0`.